# Determine the mass of a thread that looks like $y = x^2$ with density initial condition.

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

A thread has the form:

$$y = x^2, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~1 \leq x \leq 4$$

has a density that is proportional to the perpendicular distance to the $y$-axis. The density is 1 $kg/m^3$ in the point $(1,1)$. The length units of the coordinate axes is 1 m. Determine the mass of the thread.

**Attempted answer:**

This question appears deceptively simple.

The density is some constant k multiplied by the distance to the $y$-axis:

$$\rho(x) = kx$$

The initial condition $\rho(1) = k \cdot 1 = 1$ gives us $k = 1$ and so:

$$\rho(x) = x$$

Taking the integral:

$$m = \int_1^4 \rho(x)dx = \int_1^4 x dx = \Big[\frac{x^2}{2} \Big]_1^4 = \frac{16}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{15}{2}$$

The expected answer is very, very different:

$$m = \frac{1}{12}(65^{3/2}-5^{3/2})$$

Something has gone very wrong. What are some productive ways to get this attempt on the right track and finish it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ds=\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx=\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx;$

$dm=\rho (x) ds;$

$m=\int_{1}^{4}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx$;

$u=1+4x^2$:

$\displaystyle{\int_{5}^{65}}(1/8)√udu=$

$(2/3)(1/8)u^{3/2} \big ]_{5}^{65}=$

$(1/12)[65^{3/2}-5^{3/2}].$